# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need realize simple example with retrofit. I use next

gradle dependensy:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

Interface:

```
public interface TestService {
        @GET("test")
        Test getUser();
    }
```

in main activity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                TestService service = retrofit.create(TestService.class);
                Test test = service.getUser();
                Log.d("button_click", "test: "+ test);
            }
        });
```

error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class mydomain.nfpclient.models.Test.
  Tried:
   * retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
   * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your interface:

```
public interface TestService {
    @GET("test")
    Call<Test> getUser(); //Call<Test> instead of just Test
}
```

Then, use it like this:

**Synchronous**

```
Response<Test> response = service.getUser().execute();
```

**Asynchronous**

```
service.getUser().enqueue(new Callback<Test>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Test> response) {
        //handle successful response
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

You can get the `Test` from a `Response<Test>` by calling `response.body()`.

If you are using RxJava integration, use `Observable` instead of `Call`:

```
public interface TestService {
    @GET("test")
    Observable<Test> getUser();
}
```

and

```
service.getUser().subscribe(
    user -> ,//do something with your user,
    error -> //something wrong happened
);
```